# Printing the result in Google Sheet Console to the page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found this function at [How to get all tab names/gid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60086327/13045193):

```js
function GetTabs() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.openById('1e4zL13L2b8Hs8sJcBw-3_pGjQBecZv_QO_LuSLUrieA');
  var name = ss.getName();
  Logger.log(name);
  var tabs = new Array()
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) tabs.push([sheets[i].getSheetId()])
  //return tabs  
  Logger.log(tabs)
}
```

It lets me print the GID number of tabs in a spreadsheet to the console. How do I put these GIDs on Sheet2 of the active spreadsheet instead?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Sheet.appendRow()`, like this:

```js
function appendSheetIdsToSheet2() {
  const sheetToPrintTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet 2');
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1e4zL13L2b8Hs8sJcBw-3_pGjQBecZv_QO_LuSLUrieA');
  sheetToPrintTo.appendRow([ss.getName()]);
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sheet => sheetToPrintTo.appendRow([sheet.getSheetId()]));
}
```

Comment: 0


I'm stupid..

Let me explain, I have an xlsx file, I open it with google sheet, I cannot make changes in this file.

I created an E table with this e table and I want to get the gid codes when I open my XLSX file

Comment: Please do not present new requirements after you received an answer. Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.